# Mysql Query For Embed Code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like :

```
         insert into tbl(embed) values('<embed width="100%" height="320" flashvars="config=http://server18.stream2k.com/playerjw/vConfig56.php?vkey=f3513b19d1149102e116" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" src="http://server18.stream2k.com/playerjw/player-licensed56.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent">');
```

But it's not working .Can anyone tell me how can i make it working?

THanks,

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that query. We can't help you if you don't help us understand your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
"INSERT INTO tbl(embed) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($embedded_code)."')";
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: @diEcho I posted that prior to your editing your answer, when you weren't concatenating things.